# Line graph with color by numeric variable

Tags: r

My dataset:

```
data = data.frame(
  product_id = c(123, 123, 123,123, 952, 952,952),
  year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3),
  sales = c(1000000, 93485, 1593800, 1720000, 893200, 1027000, 991830)
)
```

Expectation: I want to generate a line graph showing the trend of the 2 products ("123" and "952") from year 1-4 (There is only available data from year 1-3 for product "952").
My code:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = product_id))
```

However, the plot created with this code makes me confused and was not the one I expected.
Is there something wrong with the code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add factor with your color into it like below, The problem is with your product_id taken as continuous scale hence unable `ggplot` unable to categorize it well, The same can be achieved by using group option inside aes but the colors of line wouldn't still be on categorical scale(two lines will show with different variation of blue). You can choose any option, but first one is better.

```
# option1
# This version will show two lines with categorical scale 
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=year, y=sales)) +
   geom_line(aes(color = factor(product_id)))


#option2
# This version will show two lines but with continuous scale
data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=year, y=sales, group=product_id)) +
geom_line(aes(color = product_id))
```

EDIT:

After OP requested for custom colors, we can use scale_color_manual, If you want to know what colors name could be taken , one can run `colors()` command in prompt to see the colour support:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(product_id))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red', 'green'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to choose colors, for example, red for "123" and green for "952"?